# Start activity when notification is pressed

Tags: android, android-notifications

My method according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("MyApp")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ActionActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

This does just start the MainActivity, but I want it to start the ActionActivity. Do you see any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add ActionActivity on the place of MainActivity

```
 // Adds the back stack
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ActionActivity.class);
```

Comment: Still same problem, only main activity is opened

Comment: @artworkadシ means problem solved and what code you used with stackBuilder or without it?

Comment: yeah still used stackBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Remove **stackBuilder** and Try like this.In my case its working..

```
Intent notificationIntent =new Intent(context,ActionActivity.class);
// set intent so it does not start a new activity
   notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
   PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
   this.notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
   this.notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   // Play default notification sound
      this.notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
   // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
      this.notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
      notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```